# What does (+) mean in SQLPlus?

Tags: sql, oracle

I just stumbled across a SQL+-Query which uses `(+)`. I've never worked with SQL+ before and I've never seen something like this. I tried to ask Google about it, but I couldn't find anything useful since Google obviously filters the "(+)" and just ignores it...

Example:

```
[...]
where [...] 
    AND 16791688 = T7mm.child_fielddef_id  (+)  
    AND T7mm.parent_dbid = T7.dbid  (+) 
    AND T1.dbid <> 0 [...]
```

Comment: Look at the Oracle documentation for joins

Comment: I would suggest using http://symbolhound.com/ for searching something like that see [the results](http://symbolhound.com/?q=%28%2B%29+oracle)

Comment: @ConradFrix possible, though I searched for it on SO and didn't find that particular question. Thanks for the enlightment anyways :)

Comment: It would be better to rewrite this using LEft joins if the version of Oracle you are using supports them.

Comment: Vince - check out the link from Conrad, which will answer your question. Basically the (+) is old syntax for an outer join. Also note that it's an Oracle thing, not a SQLPlus thing.

Comment: @Vince You missed it because of what Ed Gibbs pointed out. You were looking for SQL plus instead of Oracle and also because as you pointed out (+) is hard to look for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is an Oracle specific shortcut for `OUTER JOIN`

Comment: hmmmm... although `(+)` is for outer joins, I wouldn't characterize it as *shortcut* in the normal sense of the word, i.e. it cannot be simply used in place of `OUTER JOIN` as its syntax is different.

Answer (score 3):

It makes the join an outer join rather than an inner join:

```
SELECT
    A.*,
    B.*
FROM
    A,
    B
WHERE
    A.ID = B.ID(+)
```

is equivalent to:

```
SELECT
    A.*,
    B.*
FROM
    A
    LEFT JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
```

The (+) notation is the old Oracle syntax for SQL queries. Now it is generally viewed as best practice to use the ANSI standard with the `LEFT JOIN` keywords instead